# Hide {{{X}}} if X parameter is empty in templates?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

Let's say that I have this code:

```
{{Equipment|1=Test1|3=Test3}}
```

And this template:

```
====Head====
: {{{1}}}
: {{{2}}}
====Shoulders====
: {{{3}}}
: {{{4}}}
====Chest====
: {{{5}}}
: {{{6}}}
====Hands====
: {{{7}}}
: {{{8}}}
====Legs====
: {{{9}}}
: {{{10}}}
====Feet====
: {{{11}}}
: {{{12}}}
```

This returns:

```
Head[edit]
Test1
{{{2}}}
Shoulders[edit]
Test3
{{{4}}}
Chest[edit]
{{{5}}}
{{{6}}}
Hands[edit]
{{{7}}}
{{{8}}}
Legs[edit]
{{{9}}}
{{{10}}}
Feet[edit]
{{{11}}}
{{{12}}}
```

Is it possible to hide the empty {{{X}}} parameters, for example, could I hide {{{2}}}, {{{4}}}, {{{5}}} etc. since they are empty and the page will just display {{{X}}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a pipe after the parameters in the template code, like `{{{2|}}}` so that they won't show up if no value is given for them.

Comment: The "pipe" signifies an "empty default value" btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an entire section to disappear you can also:

Instead of this:

```
====Hands====
: {{{7}}}
```

Do this

```
{{{7|
====Hands====
: {{{7}}}
}}}
```